# Cannot copy from MBP and paste on iPhone

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, continuity

I used to be able to use the copy/paste part of continuity just fine between my Mac and my iPhone. I can still copy from my iPhone and paste on my Mac, but I cannot copy on my Mac and paste on my iPhone. Both devices are supported. Both operating systems are supported. Both have bluetooth on and are on the same wifi network and both have handoff turned on. Any ideas?